# show dropdown Vue js and quasar in cloud firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, quasar-framework

Good morning, how do I get a firebase array and display it in a dropdown in Vue js I currently have this

I have already seen articles of yours but the truth cannot show the data of an array nor do I know how to edit them so that they can be added more but the main thing is to show the data that I am calling from firebase in a dropdown

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-md row items-start">
      <label>laboratorios</label>
      <input v-model="laboratorios" type="text" class="form-control" />
      <q-btn color="primary" @click="guardarLab()" label="Primary" />
      <q-select
        filled
        multiple
        clearable
        use-input
        use-chips
        option-label="laboratorios"
        v-model="lab"
        :options="labs"
        style="width: 250px"
      />
      <!-- <select v-model="lab">
        <option v-for="(item, index) in labs" :key="index" v-html="item.laboratorios"></option>
      </select>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from "boot/firebase"; // no olvidar importar db
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      laboratorios: "",
      nombre: null,
      lab: null,
      multiple: null,
      labs: []
      /* labs:[
        'glicemia','colesterol','trigliceridos','hemograma','perfil lipidico'
      ], */
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.leerDatos();
  },
  methods: {
    // listar laboratorios de la bd firebase
    async leerDatos() {
      try {
        const restDB = await db.collection("laboratorios").get();
        restDB.forEach(res => {
          console.log(res.id);
          const laboratorio = { laboratorios: res.data().laboratorios };
          this.labs.push(laboratorio);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    // guardar laboratorio
    guardarLab() {
      var lab1 = { laboratorios: this.laboratorios };
      this.labs.push(lab1);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

in the end it throws this at me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRjvn.png)
what I have in my Cloud Firestore database is this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxnVU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing in the individual laboratorios but instead passing in the arrays. This should fix the problem:

GUI:

```
<select v-model="lab">
    <option :value = "labItem" v-for = "labItem in labs">{{labItem}}</option>
</select>
```

Data:

```
created(){
    // LISTEN FOR LIVE UPDATES
    db.collection("laboratorios").onSnapshot(labs=>{
        // CONCATENATE THE ARRAYS OF EACH DOCUMENT INTO ONE ARRAY AND ASSIGN IT TO VUE DATA.
        this.labs = labs.docs.reduce((x,y)=>{
            return x.concat(y.data().laboratorios);
        }, [])
    })
}
```

Comment: This is incredible, I honestly believe that I could never have done this, based on your experience that I should learn since it is very difficult to find cloud firebase tutorials

Comment: and vue js tutorials

Comment: @dudeiale don't worry about it. Just keep learning and challenging yourself. Eventually you will keep finding more efficient/readable ways to write your code. Ultimately, it is a constant learning curve. I would suggest you to keep building more interesting tools and applications. Best of luck!

Comment: Good morning, a question. You answered a question with firebase and you tell me that with experience, the truth is I live in Colombia and here the experience is almost nil, since we are very behind. My question is, you have no way of how I could learn, help you  In a project or something like that to get the experience I need, I am not going to charge you for that and I would very much like to be able to help you in any project there is no other way to get in touch with you either by facebook or by Skype. My email is duvan.fe903@hotmail.com